# The command \string does not print curly braces of its argument

Tags: verbatim, strings, braces, detokenize

While printing the List of Symbols, I would like, in a draft, to print the definition commands as well. For instance, consider the following commands:

```
\providecommand{\perm}{\ensuremath{\pi}}
\providecommand{\permel}[1]{\ensuremath{\perm(#1)}}
```

and the following command for printing symbols within a table:

```
\providecommand{\symbdef}[2]{\texttt{\color{blue}\string #1} & #1 & #2}
```

Now, the code:

```
\section{List of Symbols}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\symbdef{\perm}{a permutaion} \\
\symbdef{\permel{i}}{the value of \perm for the argument $i$} \\
\end{tabular}
```

proudeces output: `\perm` and `\permeli` in the first column. However I would like to print `\permel{i}` instead of `\permlei` here and do not know how.

Please help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\string` only takes **one** token and prints that, so it only ever sees `\permel`.

Try

```
\providecommand{\symbdef}[2]{\texttt{\color{blue}\detokenize{#1}} & #1 & #2}
```

This will insert explicit spaces after control sequences, which is not semantically wrong, but might not be aesthetically pleasing. In that case, try filtering out the spaces like this:

```
\providecommand{\symbdef}[2]{\texttt{\color{blue}\expandafter\filterspaceaftercs\detokenize{#1\x}_} & #1 & #2}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\|=\z@
\catcode`\\=12
|gdef|filterspaceaftercs#1\#2 #3_%
{%
  #1%
  |ifx|empty#3|empty
    |expandafter|@gobble
   |else
    \#2|expandafter|filterspaceaftercs
  |fi
  #3_%
}
|endgroup
```

[image: example]

Comment: Which will insert spaces after control sequences, of course.

Comment: @JosephWright As does `\show` and such, so it's a feature :-) A more elegant solution probably requires *verbatim* style trickery.

Comment: Yes, I known :-) I was just contrasting it with `\string`, which does not but where you do need to do a token-by-token conversion (tricky, depending on requirements).

Comment: @JosephWright ...in which case you'd get the complementary problem with spaces...

Comment: That works, just with spaces. Not a big deal, but do you know how to remove them? Or how to solve the same problem using verbatim?

Comment: @DanielLangr Only slightly more effort... ;-)

Comment: I'm leaving the verbatim version to someone else. Paraphrasing [David Hilbert](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/David_Hilbert): "No one shall expel us from the Paradise that `\detokenize` has created."

Comment: I recoil with dismay and horror at this lamentable plague of macros which do not have expandable versions. — Charles Hermite :P

Comment: @percusse: i would recommend you don't look at the faq, then.  i suspect that documenting tex has a general tendency to stray towards (or beyond) the limit of what's "good looking" tex.  the faq certainly does.